# archive ubuntu ftp server for specific package

Tags: software-sources, archive

I am looking for accessing server for archive.ubuntu.com for specific package like python in gz tarball. Typically a list of available files are shown and you can select file based on version you need and get it in browser by just clicking on it. I am aware that source rpm can be obtained through apt-get though I am looking for ftp server listing from which to select file. I followed https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubumtu though I could not guess where something as simple as python can be obtained. I need python to untar and install through source for some work and may have to select version through lists depending on work. Please provide pointers or guide on this.

Comment: " python in gz tarball." Not possible. Ubuntu only provide "debs".  "that source rpm can be obtained through apt-get" rpm is Redhat not Ubuntu.  For sources of python see https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your real problem seems to be "*I need python to untar and install through source for some work*", The (unworkable) solution you have decided upon is to browse archive.ubuntu.com, which only provides packages instead of  tarballs (that's why it's unworkable). Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1469384/edit) to explain your real problem more clearly. An example of the problem would help a lot.

Comment: it is not just python. Earlier I wanted gcc and could not track gz tarball on archive ubuntu and got it from gnu.org which has easier way to get it through its ftp listing in browser. I already gave example of python and it is just not one problem.

Comment: As @user535733noted, that's not what archive.ubuntu.com provides. When you say "Typically a list of available files are shown" -- are you referring to an Ubuntu package site, or some other software depot that you're hoping to find an analog for?